# The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event - Error in output when attempting to run selenium based tests in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, specflow

When I am attempting to run my automated tests in Visual Studio i seem to be getting the following error. The test provider i am using is SpecFlow.NUnit. Anybody got any ideas? i am stumped...
[image: error]

**Error text:**

```
The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[19308] testhost.x86.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[19308] testhost.x86.exe' has exited with code -2147450730 (0x80008096).
```

- I have the latest up to date 2019 version of Visual Studio
- The target framework is .NET Core 2.1 which is installed

I have the following NuGet packages and versions installed
[image: specflow NuGet Packages]
[image: NUnit NuGet packages]

Comment: Can you try with setting platform on x64?

Comment: What is your address? I am sending you a medal. This has sorted it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. I don't know what is going on behind the scene, but once or twice i opened question/issue with similar problem and it turned out that changing the platform worked out.

Answer (score 4):

Stefan Zivkovic's comment helped me too.  Figure I'd put this down in an answer giving him full credit that what he suggested helped me too.

Furthermore, in order to set your test architecture: Test menu tab --> Process Architecture for AnyCPU Projects --> x64

Answer (score 1):

This error will occur when an expected dependency is missing or is of the wrong version/compatibility level when referenced in the solution.

It will occur anytime Visual Studio is trying to execute something but the call of that execution fails.

In my experience, when .net core does not have all related components installed like the hosting bundle and the shared .net framework libraries for a given SDK version, or any of the other dependency components... then this error will occur.

I've seen .net core 3.1 components installed along side .net core 5+ and this error occurs based on that alone.

If anything is wrong with the launchSettings.json for any of the build profiles, then Visual Studio's attempts at starting the application or running any of the commands in the profiles after the build will lead to this error as well.

Recently I just realized the Microsoft Browser Link library wasn't installed and it also caused this error as the launch browser option in the project was selected.

**EDIT:**

This error will also occur sometimes if browser processes are running for a select browser chosen in the debugging drop down which conflicts with VS 2019's ability to initiate a browser process for some reason.

Comment: This seems correct. It doesn't solve anything, but it is worth knowing.

Comment: @Don Rolling Thank you for the recognition! This error is a very big pain in the ass for many .Net Core devs!

Comment: I was also able to resolve this issue by removing ng build from my post build events in the asp.net 5.0 project and i added the ng build command to the start command in package.json.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you haven't installed .net Core. Currently there are 2 Core versions **2.1** and **3.1**, make sure you have installed either of them.
You can find it here : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core
Make sure to **restart** system after installation.